# How to use Application Object which init dagger with JUnit testing

Tags: android, junit, kotlin, dagger-2

Trying to start implementing testing for my application class which init dagger and instantiate appComponent with AppModule and Storage Module, I found that extends ApplicationTestCase should help and setup the application but the problem getApplication() always return null.
Is it the right way to use the application object in JUnit and why does `getApplication()` return `null`?

```
  class LirisApplication : Application() {

  companion object {
    lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
  }

  fun getDataComponent(): AppComponent {
    return appComponent
  }

  override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    initializeDagger()
    Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
  }

  private fun initializeDagger() {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .storageModule(StorageModule())
            .networkModule(NetworkModule(BuildConfig.BASE_URL))
            .build()
    }

   }
```

ApplicationTest

```
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<LirisApplication> {

    private LirisApplication application;

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(LirisApplication.class);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        createApplication();
        application = getApplication();
    }

    public void testCorrectVersion() throws Exception {
        PackageInfo info = application.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(application.getPackageName(), 0);
        assertNotNull(info);
        MoreAsserts.assertMatchesRegex("\\d\\.\\d", info.versionName);
    }

}
```

The error is in this line because the application is null

```
PackageInfo info = application.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(application.getPackageName(), 0);
```

Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at digitu.com.osmos.ApplicationTest.testCorrectVersion(ApplicationTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: You can't unit test the package manager IIRC, or anything that requires access to the Android API. Depends on what type of test it is though

Comment: I found that extend ApplicationTestCase can create the application and createApplication() call onCreate()

Comment: Oh. Ignore my comment then :)